# How to make a function take variables from outside the function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, while-loop

So I've just started to program code that will ask the user what subject they want to have a test on and how difficult they want it to be, and then, obviously, give them that test. I created a function for the if statement that checks what test it is and how difficult it should be, and I just made a random, throwaway function to test the code. I'll show you the code (obviously very early-alpha and nowhere near finished) and then I'll explain the problem.

```
def which_test(real_dif, real_test, give_test):
    if difficulty == real_dif and test == real_test:
        give_test

def easy_CS():
    print("HEY")

while True:
    test = str(input("What test do you want to take? Computer Science, History or Music? ").strip().lower())
    difficulty = str(input("Do you want to take the test in easy, medium or hard? ").strip().lower())
    which_test("easy", "computer science", easy_CS())
```

The problem is, the `easy_CS()` function gets activated no matter what the input variables are. I could input "JFAWN" for the `test` variable and "JDWNA" for the `difficulty` variable and it would still print "HEY". How do I make it so that it actually takes the variables, or how could I make it so that it just works the way it's intended to?

Comment: Using global variables should be helpful !

Comment: You're calling the function in the wrong place. You need to move the parentheses that caused it to be invoked inside `which_test`, so you're passing the *function*, not its *result*. @ChetanVasudevan that is rarely if ever true.

Comment: @chetanvasudevan why would you suggest the use of `global`? There's no need for it here.

Comment: @roganjosh, dint go through it completely just by thinking of using the concept of calling variable outside I just answered as global. But after reading above comment I realize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you *call* this function yourself. See the parentheses here? They call the function:

```
which_test("easy", "computer science", easy_CS())
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

What you meant to do:

```
def which_test(real_dif, real_test, give_test):
    if difficulty == real_dif and test == real_test:
        give_test()  # call the function

# more code...
which_test("easy", "computer science", easy_CS))
             # pass the function itself ^^^^^^
```

So, no parentheses - no function call.